# Padding a tensor until reaching required size

Tags: pytorch, padding, tensor, pad, zero-padding

I'm working with certian tensors with shape of (X,42) while X can be in a range between 50 to 70.
I want to pad each tensor that I get until it reaches a size of 70. so all tensors will be (70,42).
is there anyway to do this when I the begining size is a variable X? thanks for the help!

Comment: wouldn't you just pad by 70-X?

Answer (score 8):

Use [torch.nn.functional.pad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pad) - Pads tensor.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

source = torch.rand((3,42))
source.shape
>>> torch.Size([3, 42])
```

```py
# here, pad = (padding_left, padding_right, padding_top, padding_bottom)
source_pad = F.pad(source, pad=(0, 0, 0, 70 - source.shape[0]))
```

```py
source_pad.shape
>>> torch.Size([70, 42])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do so by:

```py
pad_x = torch.zeros((70, x.size(1)), device=x.device, dtype=x.dtype)
pad_x[:x.size(0), :] = x
```

This will give you `x_pad` with zero padding at the end of `x`